# Is $\tan(1-\frac{1}{2})$+$\tan(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4})$ +$\cdots$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following assignment question:

Is $\tan(1-\frac{1}{2})$+$\tan(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4})$+$\tan(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8})+\cdots$ convergent?

What I have tried is the following, first I re-wrote this in terms of a series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}\right)$$ then I calculated the limit of $a_n = \tan\left(1-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}\right)$ which equals to zero since we have a geometric series that converges to 1. Which means the divergence test does not give us any information. Then I tried to use the limit comparison test with $b_n = 1-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$ which if you take $u = 1-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$ we have $$\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{u->0}\frac{\tan(u)}{u} =1$$which implies that both sums converge or both diverge. So I'm stuck now trying to show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( 1-\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}\right)$ is convergent or not. Am I on the right track? any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is perfectly fine, but you've missed an important realization! Notice that the argument of the tangent function is $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ...$, and your series is really

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \tan \frac{1}{2^k}.$$

Now using your observations about how $\tan u$ and $u$ are related when $u$ is close to zero, you ought to be able to conclude convergence or divergence pretty quickly.

Comment: Wow. I totally missed that! thank you very much.

Comment: It might be interesting to show that $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\tan\frac{1}{2^k}=2(1-\cot 1)+4\sum_{j\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2j)}{(4^j-2)\pi^{2j}}$$ ;P